# Зависимость от input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть таблица вот такая, все данные подгружаются из БД, каждый раз количество столбцов может быть разное.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я её заполняю и потом нажимаю на кнопку сохранить,но мне нужно сделать так, что бы где мы оценку не поставил,то есть инпут в "кількість балі"  будет null, то и  на против соответствующие "дата складання", "тип відомості", "номер відомості" будет записываться в БД со значением null.Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: В чем собственно проблема ? Что не получается ?

Comment: Я вам помню когда-то ответил [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879845/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-select%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-input), там ничего сложного, тем более если мой код остался примерно таким же.

Comment: Покажите код обработчика формы, мне нужны названия полей в post запросе, чтобы составить ответ

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, да, но получаетсcя там когда мы вводим,то меняется просто значение селектов ,а тут мне надо что бы если поле input с количеством баллов равно налу, то и остальные должны равнятся налу при сохранении в БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.my-row')

;[...rows].forEach(function (row) {
  const input = row.querySelector('.my-input')
  const select1 = row.querySelector('.my-select1')
  const select2 = row.querySelector('.my-select2')
  const myDate = row.querySelector('.my-date')
  let oldInput = input.value
  
  input.oninput = function () {
    const val = input.value
    const options = [...select1.options]
    const optionsFiltered = options.filter(i => +i.dataset.value >= val)
    const option = optionsFiltered[optionsFiltered.length - 1]
    
    if (val === '') {
      myDate.value = null
      select1.selectedIndex = select2.selectedIndex = 0
      return
    }

    if (!option) {
      input.value = oldInput
      return alert('Не допустимая оценка')
    }

    const index = options.indexOf(option)

    select1.selectedIndex = select2.selectedIndex = index
    oldInput = val
  }
})
```

```css
.my-row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-row">
  <input class="my-input" type="number">

  <select class="my-select1">
    <option disabled selected hidden value=""></option>
    <option data-value="100" value="божественно">божественно</option>
    <option data-value="70" value="отлично">отлично</option>
    <option data-value="40" value="хорошо">хорошо</option>
    <option data-value="10" value="плохо">плохо</option>
    <option data-value="0" value="отвратительно">отвратительно</option>
  </select>

  <select class="my-select2">
    <option disabled selected hidden value=""></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
  </select>
  
  <input class="my-date" type="date">
</div>

<div class="my-row">
  <input class="my-input" type="number">

  <select class="my-select1">
    <option disabled selected hidden value=""></option>
    <option data-value="100" value="божественно">божественно</option>
    <option data-value="70" value="отлично">отлично</option>
    <option data-value="40" value="хорошо">хорошо</option>
    <option data-value="10" value="плохо">плохо</option>
    <option data-value="0" value="отвратительно">отвратительно</option>
  </select>

  <select class="my-select2">
    <option disabled selected hidden value=""></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>F</option>
  </select>
  
  <input class="my-date" type="date">
</div>
```

Comment: Опять вы мне помогли)А как только обратно вернуть, допустим мы случайно ввели, а потом надо удалить, и оно обнулит все остальное

Comment: Вы решите как лучше сделать, я сделал как в вопросе, если пустое поле, то остальное становится пустыми.

Comment: Понял, буду думать как лучше сделать тогда.Спасибо за быструю помощь)